# How to validate YAML file in R sdio

Tags: r, file, validation, yaml

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE);

if (length(args) < 1) {
    stop("Usage: args[0] research_question.yml")
} else {
    yml <- args[1];
}

yaml::read_yaml(yml)
```

using that code how do we validate my yaml file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

`Rscript validate_yaml.R research_question.yml`

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.